# grab values from input box with php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wondering if it would be possible to have a php file grab data from a  html page with an input box, so that the user enters a word, and the php runs using that word in the script once the user hits enter. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you  would need to do AJAX for this. PHP is a preprocessor and the code that you have on the page has already completed prior to the user ever even seeing the content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest or if you prefer jQuery ... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The form submits to a PHP page that receives the data entered into the input. Pretty basic.

Comment: thankyou both for the answers, but without sounding too ungrateful, do you know of any examples I could look at to get a better idea?

Comment: You could make the PHP script that writes in a file, and a JS function that sends the input text value via GET to the PHP file when a user press the Enter button.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: thank you AbraCadaver, I think I understand this concept now. Thank you all for your time and input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a form with the method attribute set to ‘get’ or ‘post’ like this:

```
<form method=“post”>
    <input type=“text” name=“test” value=“test” />
    <button type=“submit”>submit</button>
</form>
```

Then on the same php page, use this to get the result, store it in a variable and output it:

```
<?php

    $result = $_POST[‘test’];
    echo $result;

?>
```

More information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form

Hope the formatting in this answer is ok, typed it out on my mobile phone.